# ACT! - Export or Read an ACT table?

Tags: dbf

I need a copy of the Groups/Companies Contact List. How can Export or read it from another? I found one large dbf file but when opening in excel first few column come in garbled.

Answer (score 0):

[Use ACT itself?](http://kb.sagesoftwareonline.com/cgi-bin/sagesoftwareonline.cfg/php/enduser/std_alp.php?p_sid=mAtgl-Sj&p_lva=&p_li=&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_page=1&p_cv=&p_pv=1.6512&p_prods=6512&p_cats=&p_hidden_prods=&prod_lvl1=6512&prod_lvl2=0&p_search_text=export&srch_btn_submit=+++Find+++&p_new_search=1&p_search_type=answers.search_nl)

Edit, after comment and using the above link to filter for Jurassic versisons

[one](http://kb.sagesoftwareonline.com/cgi-bin/sagesoftwareonline.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=10683&p_created=1120078552&p_sid=pb_nB3Tj&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MTQxLDE0MSZwX3Byb2RzPTY1MTIsMTI1MyZwX2NhdHM9JnBfcHY9Mi4xMjUzJnBfY3Y9JnBfc2VhcmNoX3R5cGU9YW5zd2Vycy5zZWFyY2hfbmwmcF9wYWdlPTEmcF9zZWFyY2hfdGV4dD1leHBvcnQ*&p_li=&p_topview=1) and [two](http://kb.sagesoftwareonline.com/cgi-bin/sagesoftwareonline.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=11616&p_created=1120137629&p_sid=pb_nB3Tj&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MTQxLDE0MSZwX3Byb2RzPTY1MTIsMTI1MyZwX2NhdHM9JnBfcHY9Mi4xMjUzJnBfY3Y9JnBfc2VhcmNoX3R5cGU9YW5zd2Vycy5zZWFyY2hfbmwmcF9wYWdlPTEmcF9zZWFyY2hfdGV4dD1leHBvcnQ*&p_li=&p_topview=1)

Comment: I'm using Act ver 6. I don't see how I can export Groups.